# Login Failed Error Message Django Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a project made with function based views. I need to show an `error` message when the user enters the wrong password, but in every forum I've seen so far there is a suggestion to use a `Form`. There is no way to show an error message with the project done this way?

*view.py*:

```
def login(request):
     if request.method == "GET":
          return render(request, 'users/login.html')
     else:
          Email = request.POST.get('Email')
          Senha = request.POST.get('Senha')
          user = authenticate(username=Email, password=Senha)

          if user:
               loginDjango(request, user)
               return render(request, 'convite/cadastro_convite.html')
          else:
               return redirect('login')
```

*html*:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 login-dir">
     <h2 class="login-titulo">Faça seu login!</h2>
     <form class="login-form" action="{% url 'login'%}" method="POST"> 
          {% csrf_token %}

          <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="log-email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
               <input type="password" class="form-control" id="log-senha" name="Senha" placeholder="Senha">
          </div>

          <button href="/Exemplo" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary login-btn_dir">
               <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i> Acessar
          </button>
     </form>
</div>
```

*model*:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    NomeUsuario = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Endereco = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Celular = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Cidade = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Estado = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Cep = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Bairro = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it seems using a `django` `form` is more efficient, yes there is a way you could do it from what you have by just adding a few lines of code.

But here's my first recommendation... Rename your defined method called `login` to `loginDjango`. By doing that you could use the `django` `login` method without having any potential issues.

You can use the code below to solve your problem:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def loginDjango(request):
     context = {}         

     if request.method == "GET":
          return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
     else:
          found = False

          Email = request.POST.get('Email')
          Senha = request.POST.get('Senha')
          
          # Try retrieving the user object from the get_user_model method
          user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), email=Email) # Assuming the email field is unique.

          # If a user object was returned then you can use the check_password method on the user object.
          if user:
               if user.check_password(Senha): # If the passwords matched
                    found = True
               else:
                    context['password_error'] = 'You have entered an incorrect password!'
          else:
               context['email_error'] = "Sorry, this email address doesn't exist!"
          
          # If the email exists and the password match then found is true...
          # Can use the authenticate within this if statement
          if found:
               # From the user object, using user.username -> username=user.username
               user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=Senha)
               
               # This if statement is not really necessary again but you can have it as a fail-safe
               if user:
                    # Use the django login method to log the user in.
                    login(request, user)
                    return render(request, 'convite/cadastro_convite.html')
          
          return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
```

Then within your template, you can check for the errors you sent via the context dictionary.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="log-email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
     {% if email_error %}<span>{{ email_error }}</span>{% endif %}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="log-senha" name="Senha" placeholder="Senha">
     {% if password_error %}<span>{{ password_error }}</span>{% endif %}
</div>
```

But I do recommend that you give [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/) a read for the `djano forms` as well though.